# Need to process 200 Million record using Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am cleaning the data ( approx 200 Million rows) using python Pyspark but getting the error:

ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)

The size of the csv file is 21 GB and I added `config('spark.driver.memory','8g')` and I am using Macbook Pro 16GB.

When I try to process the same file by reducing the size to 1GB, it executes successfully.

Any recommendations!!

I am using Apache 2.4

Expected results: To process the raw_data.csv file 
Actual results: base =

```
base[:pos] + unichr(char) + base[pos:]
ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)
```

Comment: Can you tell us the value of `char`?  And perhaps show some of the code surrounding the line mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Can you share your code, or a simplified sample of it that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be related to an unescaped unicode character in your `char` variable.  Could you try using:

```
base = base[:pos] + char.decode('unicode-escape') + base[pos:]
```

Including your code would make it easier to help debug the issue.